# missing_GET_variables | is there a way determine where or what is the missing variable

Tags: php, forms, variables, get, message

In my activation code it says missing_GET_variables, i can't seem to find the missing get variable? In my activation code it has ...

```
if ( isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['u']) && isset($_GET['e']) && isset($_GET['p']) ) {
```

Then at the bottom it has..

```
} else {
    // Log this issue of missing initial $_GET variables
    header("location: message.php?msg=missing_GET_variables");
    exit(); 
}
```

And someone told me to look in my signup page,

```
    $message = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>yoursite Message</title>
</head><body style="margin:0px; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;"><div style="padding:10px; background:#333; font-size:24px; color:#CCC;">
<a href="http://www.yoursite.com">
<img src="http://www.yoursite.com/images/logo.png"; width="36" height="30" alt="yoursite logo" style="border:none; float:left;"></a>yoursite Account Activation</div>
<div style="padding:24px; font-size:17px;">Hello '.$u.',<br />
<br />Click the link below to activate your account when ready:<br /><br />
<a href="http://www.yoursite.com/activation.php?id=&apos;.$uid.'&u='.$u.'&e='.$e.'&p='.$p_hash.'">Click here to activate your account now</a><br />
<br />Login after successful activation using your:<br />* E-mail Address: <b>'.$e.'</b></div></body></html>';
```

He only gave me that clue, but apparently I just can't seem to find it. I know people might or might not help me and that fine. But Its worth a try isn't it, to at least ask.

Comment: Remove the `isset` wrappers and find out.

Comment: You know that you can check all your variables with one call to `isset()`: `if(isset($_GET['id'], $_GET['u'], $_GET['e'], $_GET['p'])) {`

Answer (score 0):

Three ways to move forward:

Either use this to see all $_GET:

```
}else{
    print_r($_GET);
    //header("location: message.php?msg=missing_GET_variables");
    //exit();
}
```

Or use this to see which one is breaking:

```
}else{
   $id=$_GET['id']
   $u=$_GET['u']
   $e=$_GET['e']
   $p=$_GET['p']
}
```

Or set default values to handle that condition proactively (in place ofthe whole IF):

```
$id=(isset($_GET['id'])) ? $_GET['id']: [a good id];
$u=(isset($_GET['u'])) ? $_GET['u']: [a good u];
$e=(isset($_GET['e'])) ? $_GET['e']: [a good e];
$p=(isset($_GET['p'])) ? $_GET['p']: [a good p];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Since im still a beginner where do I put that in the activation code under where?

Comment: Since you're dropping into the Else only if something's wrong, I'd suggest you use the print_r in the else

Comment: when i find out what variable is breaking, do i need to see where it is missing in my signup page?

Comment: Troubleshooting can take many directions, but checking the source of the data is one good place to begin.

Answer (score 0):

You have an `apos;` html entity instead of a `'` in your `$message`.

Use:

```
$message = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>yoursite Message</title></head><body style="margin:0px; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;"><div style="padding:10px; background:#333; font-size:24px; color:#CCC;"><a href="http://www.yoursite.com"><img src="http://www.yoursite.com/images/logo.png"; width="36" height="30" alt="yoursite logo" style="border:none; float:left;"></a>yoursite Account Activation</div><div style="padding:24px; font-size:17px;">Hello '.$u.',<br /><br />Click the link below to activate your account when ready:<br /><br /><a href="http://www.yoursite.com/activation.php?id='.$uid.'&u='.$u.'&e='.$e.'&p='.$p_hash.'">Click here to activate your account now</a><br /><br />Login after successful activation using your:<br />* E-mail Address: <b>'.$e.'</b></div></body></html>';
```

Comment: Also avoid overly long lines of code, they just obfuscate your work and make the a real pain to troubleshoot.